# Can't find music transferred from RhythmBox (Ubuntu PC) to iPhone

Tags: iphone, music, unix

I've transferred a single song to my iPhone 5 through RhythmBox from my Ubuntu PC, however, when I open the "Music" app, it's not showing there. But in RhythmBox, it does show it's present.

RhythmBox:

[image]

iPhone:

[image]

Comment: What version of iOS is in use on your iPhone? Does RhythmBox support that version? It's possible it placed the file on the device, but didn't do so in a way that the the device recognizes it.

Comment: It's using version 8.3.